# Inferring type from a sibling in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Is it possible in TypeScript to infer the type of an attribute in from sibling attribute?

```
type Control = {
   Component?: React.Component
   props: Props<React.Component>
}
```

I know that it is possible by passing a generic through `Control` like the following:

```
type Control<T> = {
   Component?: T
   props: Props<T>
}
```

but my case is a little complex as I have to use `Control` inside a heterogeneous array. e.g., each `MyType` will wrap a different type of component:

```
type FormControls = Control[]

const controls: FormControls = [{
     Component: Input,
     props: {} // I need to enforce that the developer can only provide props of Input
},{
     Component: Date,
     props: {} // I need to enforce that the developer can only provide props of Date
}]
```

I can think of tuple as I solution for this but that won't be dynamic. Is there a dynamic solution for this?

Comment: a `type` like that is not possible if you don't know which Components might be passed beforehand. But you can use a generic function to do the validation for you as demonstrated [here](https://tsplay.dev/WkkGDW). Would this answer your question?

Comment: Alternatively, if you have a select few components that you want to allow, you could also just generate a union of them. Is this what you need?